# Parse Server local install not working using Getting Started guide

Tags: python-3.x, parse-platform

I am setting up a local Parse Server using the instructions found here:

```
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server#locally
```

It seems to be running but when I go to `http://localhost:1337/parse` I get an authentication error. I also tried using python:

```
import json
from http import client

connection = client.HTTPConnection('localhost', 80)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/parse/sites/cheese', json.dumps({
   "url": "http://www.cheese.com",
   "name": "I love cheese!"
 }), {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "myappid",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 })

results = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print (results)
```

However, I get:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

I assume the response is an error object or something.

In any case, there doesn't seem to be a way to configure anything and the getting started docs doesn't explicitly indicate how to add an "X-Parse-REST-API-Key".

If I look in the directory where installed parse there is just a `logs` directory. Nothing else. I would expect that there would be a configuration file or something. Any pointers on how I can get a parse server running?

Comment: when you say "I go to http://localhost:1337/parse", do you mean opening it on a web browser? This is actually the address of your API. If you want to open the dashboard, you need to start it from a different package. Take a look in this link here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For saving an object using Python to Parse Server, write a code like this:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('POST', '/parse/classes/GameScore', json.dumps({
       "score": 1337,
       "playerName": "Sean Plott",
       "cheatMode": False
     }), {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "${APPLICATION_ID}",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "${REST_API_KEY}",
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
     })
results = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print results
```

You can check in this link here:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#creating-objects

Note that there is a Python option in the sample code.